# can I use Geometry shader to delete points

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to delete some points use Geometry shader, Is there a function to do this work?
I know there is a function to add points.

```
gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4(-0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0);
EmitVertex();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a special function for that. As long as you don't add them (`EmitVertex`), they are practically deleted.

Comment: I had find a solution, I set the positions of pionts I want to delete out of the range of screen in vertex shader.